# Django POST with url argument impossible

Tags: django

I use django generic views POST

```
    def post(request,pk):
        poll = get_object_or_404(Poll,pk=pk)
        try:
            selected_item = poll.item_set.get(pk=request.POST['id'])
        except (KeyError,Item.DoesNotExist):
            return redirect("polls:detail")
        else:
            selected_item.votes += 1
            selected_item.save()
            return redirect('https://www.google.com')
```

But I got POST multiple argument. This is my url.

```
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/vote$',views.PollVoteView.as_view(),name="vote")
```

Comment: Could you add the stacktrace of the error that you're getting?

Comment: If you truly are using generic views, then you missed out the `self` parameter

Comment: +Sayse Where should I place self?

Comment: def post(self, request, pk)

Answer (score 0):

I really forgot to place `self` parameter. Thank you. Sayse